# Sort pandas df based on balances

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dummy df:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create the initial DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'car': ['Pickup', 'Racer', 'Lorry', 'Luxury', 'Cabrio', 'Bicycle', 'Truck'],
                   'old_owner': ['1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '3', '1'],
                   'new_owner': ['2', '3', '2', '1', '1', '1', '1']})

print(df)
>>> 
           car old_owner new_owner
0   Pickup         1         2
1    Racer         1         3
2    Lorry         1         2
3   Luxury         2         1
4   Cabrio         2         1
5  Bicycle         3         1
6    Truck         1         1
```

I want to sort it such that no one can have a lower car balance of -1 than originally. So, I need to directly (next row) assign the person I took a car from a car again.
Also, I always have to start with "removing" a car from one.
So, I cannot do

```
0   Pickup         2         1
1    Racer         1         2
```

but rather

```
0   Pickup         1         2
1    Racer         2         1
```

Dummy df should look like this:

```
       car old_owner new_owner
0    Racer         1         3
1  Bicycle         3         1
2   Luxury         2         1
3   Pickup         1         2
4   Cabrio         2         1
5    Lorry         1         2
6    Truck         1         1
```

As follows my code:

```
car_counts = df['old_owner'].append(df['new_owner']).value_counts().to_dict()

# Create a function to sort the DataFrame based on the car counts
def custom_sort(row):
    if row['old_owner'] == '1':
        return car_counts[row['new_owner']], car_counts[row['old_owner']]
    return car_counts[row['old_owner']], -car_counts[row['new_owner']]

# Sort the DataFrame using the custom sort function
df = df.assign(sort_key=df.apply(custom_sort, axis=1))
df = df.sort_values(by='sort_key')

# Reset the index and drop the 'sort_key' column
df = df.reset_index(drop=True).drop(columns=['sort_key'])

print(df)
```

It outputs this:

```
>>>
0  Bicycle         3         1
1    Racer         1         3
2   Luxury         2         1
3   Cabrio         2         1
4   Pickup         1         2
5    Lorry         1         2
6    Truck         1         1
```

As you see, row 3 & 4 should be switched as "2" would have -2 cars but can only have -1.

I am using 1,2,3 as owner number to make it easier but in reality these would be around higher digits number like 12344 or 674849. (like an account number)

Comment: This seems to me like a mathematical optimization problem, rather than sorting. So do you want to minimize user's balance but don't want the user's balance to be -2 or lower?

Comment: @AndrejKesely -1 or lower, yes

Comment: "So do you want to minimize user's balance". In a sense yes. I mean I just want to reassign cars but without giving anyone more cars than they originally had and also not less. -1 is needed as I otherwise cannot remove a car from someone. But right after 2x assign+reassign the balance should be normal again for both people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can try:

```py
from itertools import zip_longest


def reorder(g):
    g = g.sort_values("old_owner")

    idx_split = g["old_owner"].idxmax()

    all_data = []
    for r1, r2 in zip_longest(
        g.loc[: idx_split - 1].itertuples(),
        g.loc[idx_split:].itertuples(),
    ):
        if r1 is not None:
            all_data.append(r1)
        if r2 is not None:
            all_data.append(r2)

    return (
        pd.DataFrame(all_data).set_index("Index").rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
    )


out = (
    df.groupby(df[["old_owner", "new_owner"]].apply(frozenset, axis=1))
    .apply(reorder)
    .droplevel(0)
)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
       car old_owner new_owner
6    Truck         1         1
0   Pickup         1         2
3   Luxury         2         1
2    Lorry         1         2
4   Cabrio         2         1
1    Racer         1         3
5  Bicycle         3         1
```

Comment: interesting, the df on the first line of "out" is an empty one, right? Currently getting the error that"df" is not defined

Comment: @Exa Yes, the `df` is the same as defined in your question.

Comment: Using that df I am getting "TypeError: reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype" at .apply(reorder)

Comment: @Exa What datatype do you have there? Can you convert it to numbers? (for example using Categorical)?

Comment: ah good one, thanks!     "g['old_owner'] = g['old_owner'].astype(int)"  did the trick. Now it works on my dummy df. Trying it now on my larger df.

Comment: on my larger df I am getting "    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 9297". I need to investigate what's going on there a bit more.

Comment: odd, a row at that index does exist.

Comment: At "for r1, r2 in zip_longest(
        g.loc[: idx_split - 1].itertuples(),"
I am getting said KeyError:9297. Right before idx_split is 9298. So, [:idx_split:-1] would give 9297. Index 9297 is not yet in all_data. At the same time I can see it in my input df. So the index exists. Not sure why it cannot find it. Any idea?